# Detect whether WiFi data is enabled or not?

Tags: android, android-wifi, android-wireless

I need to know how to detect the WiFi state where i am getting the `true` return on checking `isNetworkconnected()` via `ConnectivityManager`, but actually the response is manipulated by the respected WIFI server.

Suppose I visited some place where WIFI is free but I need to login to that network for accessing, but in the mean time if I start my app without login to that wifi, I will get the WIFI connected return `true` via `ConnectivityManager` (as android only check if WIFI is connected or not), and some unexpected response from that wifi host.

How can I detect such kind of connectivity? I have seen multiple apps loader running in such case, but how they detect it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to be able to test via the connectivity manager. The result will always be unreliable for the reasons you've stated.

So, as I see it, you have two options:

1)  You test the Wi-Fi's SSID on like an approved list or something, and if the user isn't on that SSID, you alert them.

Here's the method to get the SSID of the currently connected router (iOS 7+):

```
@import SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork;

/** Returns first non-empty SSID network info dictionary.
 *  @see CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo */
- (NSDictionary *)fetchSSIDInfo
{
    NSArray *interfaceNames = CFBridgingRelease(CNCopySupportedInterfaces());
    NSLog(@"%s: Supported interfaces: %@", __func__, interfaceNames);

    NSDictionary *SSIDInfo;
    for (NSString *interfaceName in interfaceNames) {
        SSIDInfo = CFBridgingRelease(
        CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo((__bridge CFStringRef)interfaceName));
        NSLog(@"%s: %@ => %@", __func__, interfaceName, SSIDInfo);

        BOOL isNotEmpty = (SSIDInfo.count > 0);
        if (isNotEmpty) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return SSIDInfo;
}
```

2)  I suggest that you forget trying to test wi-fi with these standard methods, and you simply fire a request with a timeout of like 3s before you try to use the Wi-Fi. If you get a valid response, you are connected, else it has failed.

Comment: Hi Sharma, it's hard for me to say as I don't know what you're trying to do with the Wi-Fi connection. The data that you're intending to receive over Wi-Fi is the request you should make.

Comment: If that doesn't make sense, let me know :)

Comment: I just want to detect if any firewall is manipulating the actual response of my web request . what I am getting as response is a long html code of login page instead of normal JSOn response . so i am catching the error in catch block as i am unable to parse that. and all this is happening because the local connection(firewall or (guest management system application)) of user is manipulating the response.  Let me know if i am unable to express what i actually want..

Comment: Right, so what i'm suggesting is that this parse error catch block is what you use as a means of detecting whether it's failed or not. you could just make a small method that just does that request and returns a bool if it's a valid response or not, and if it's not, it's failed. i feel this is slightly falling outside the scope of the original question though.

Comment: That is what I am currently doing .. you made me comfortable to this approach.. Thanks..

Comment: great :) accept answer if you will, i've updated it to reflect the comments